# Dockerfile runs runs locally but fails on Google Cloud Run

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-run, prefect

I have a Dockerfile, shown below:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 prefecthq/prefect:2-python3.12

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install libpq-dev gcc
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv

ENV PREFECT_API_URL="foo"
ENV PREFECT_API_KEY="bar"

WORKDIR /app

COPY Pipfile Pipfile
COPY Pipfile.lock Pipfile.lock

RUN pipenv install --deploy --ignore-pipfile

COPY . .

CMD ["pipenv", "run", "python", "src/cdk_flow/cdk_delta_flow.py"]
```

This file builds and runs successfully locally, but when pushing it to [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) (using [Prefect](https://docs.prefect.io/latest/) to push it), it fails to run with the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/src/cdk_flow/cdk_delta_flow.py", line 7, in <module>
    from src.cdk_flow.cdk_common_tasks import (
  File "/app/src/cdk_flow/cdk_common_tasks.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Why would the Dockerfile run locally but fail to find a module on Google Cloud Run

Comment: Seems like you are missing adding the pandas in your Dockerfile. Seems like the latest python version image doesn't have pandas preinstalled and manually you will need to add it to your Dockerfile. Also make sure the installed [pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases/tag/v2.2.0) package is compatible with the python version.

Comment: Also can you share the correct `Dockerfile` and all required files to replicate the issue?

Comment: Why are you using `pipenv` to build a Docker image? That is not needed or recommended. Create the `requiements.txt` file so that required dependencies are installed.

Comment: It may not be needed or recommended, but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work. I'm using Pipenv for this project and would prefer to deploy without having to keep a `Pipfile` and `requirements.txt` in sync with one another.

The docker image runs fine locally, so I'm skeptical that this is an issue with pipenv. Having said that, I'll give it a try with `requirements.txt` instead.

Comment: It is of course your choice, but why introduce additional layers that must be tested and documented? Using `pipenv` in a Dockerfile would not pass my team's code review.

Comment: I've yet to try with `requirements.txt` but it does seem like this may be a [known Cloud Run bug with pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4174)

Comment: Your post does not show how you use Prefect to push the image. Edit your post to provide all the details to reproduce your problem. Using third-party tools is fine, but I recommend first learning how to build and deploy containers using documented Google Cloud steps first so that you understand how to debug problems.

Answer (score 0):

Running `Pipenv` inside a Dockerfile doesn't play nicely with Google Cloud Run. In order to avoid a module not found error we must declare

`ENV PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT 1` in our Dockerfile. More detail in [this thread](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4174)